# How to get the value from the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm working on a project where I use CKEditor. I have an panel with several properties to create a tooltip. I choose CKEditor to insert the content into the tooltip, because its great for the users.

All works fine if I use a normal textarea to insert the content I want. But instead a normal textarea i want to use CKEditor. I don't know what happened but the tooltip doesn't get the content I write.

Someone can give me hand?

```
// Normal textarea, this works
<textarea id="editor1" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

The script with CKEditor:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

I have read about the JavaScript code to insert `ckeditor.instances`... and so on, but i can't figure it out how it works.

Comment: if you include ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js as a javascript file aswell as ckeditor/ckeditor.js you can use jquery to apply ckeditor:  $("#editor1").ckeditor();  you have to include the jquery adapter file for it to work.

Comment: i have tried this.. but still dont add the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor library registers a [global variable](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR) (object) `CKEDITOR` (refers to `window.CKEDITOR`):

```
console.log( CKEDITOR );
> Object {...}
```

When you [create an instance](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed-section-1), let's say with `CKEDITOR.replace()`, it's registered in `CKEDITOR.instances` [object](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-instances). The key in this object corresponds to the name of the instance.

```
console.log( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1 );
> Object {...}
```

This is the way you access the API of your editor, until you destroy it. So if you want to [retrieve data](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed-section-3) from your editor, basically call:

```
console.log( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData() );
> "<p>Some text</p>"
```

If you want to use jQuery to play with CKEditor, there's an [official wrapper (adapter)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) for CKEditor API.

Also, considering the fact that you want to use CKEditor to produce HTML for some tooltip, you may want to avoid creating paragraphs by the editor (default behavior). You can do that by setting the [configuration option](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-enterMode): `config.enterMode` to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR`. See [the article](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) about configuring CKEditor.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

[**Documentation**](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-for-jQuery)

```
$('#editor1').ckeditor(); // to add ckeditor to textbox

$('#editor1').val(); // fetching value from textbox
```

don't forget to add `jQuery` files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js">
```

Comment: no... nothing happend... that is the problem, because i dont get any error